# Why the selector status.PostgresClusterStatus=Running does not work?

Tags: kubernetes

I have displayed the following resource as yaml:

```
kubectl get postgresql databaker-users-db -o yaml
apiVersion: acid.zalan.do/v1
kind: postgresql
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: user-db
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
  creationTimestamp: "2020-06-16T15:58:28Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    team: databaker
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: acid.zalan.do/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:meta.helm.sh/release-name: {}
          f:meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: {}
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {}
          f:team: {}
      f:spec:
        .: {}
        f:databases:
          .: {}
          f:users: {}
        f:numberOfInstances: {}
        f:postgresql:
          .: {}
          f:version: {}
        f:resources:
          .: {}
          f:limits:
            .: {}
            f:cpu: {}
            f:memory: {}
          f:requests:
            .: {}
            f:cpu: {}
            f:memory: {}
        f:teamId: {}
        f:users:
          .: {}
          f:databaker: {}
        f:volume:
          .: {}
          f:size: {}
    manager: Go-http-client
    operation: Update
    time: "2020-06-16T15:58:28Z"
  - apiVersion: acid.zalan.do/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        .: {}
        f:PostgresClusterStatus: {}
    manager: postgres-operator
    operation: Update
    time: "2020-06-16T15:58:53Z"
  name: databaker-users-db
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "68486"
  selfLink: /apis/acid.zalan.do/v1/namespaces/default/postgresqls/databaker-users-db
  uid: 8bc3b591-4346-4cca-a1ae-682a1ad16615
spec:
  databases:
    users: databaker
  numberOfInstances: 2
  postgresql:
    version: "12"
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 500m
      memory: 500Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 100Mi
  teamId: databaker
  users:
    databaker:
    - superuser
    - createdb
  volume:
    size: 2Gi
status:
  PostgresClusterStatus: Running
```

When I try to select with:

```
kubectl get postgresql --field-selector status.PostgresClusterStatus=Running
```

it shows error message:

```
Error from server (BadRequest): Unable to find "acid.zalan.do/v1, Resource=postgresqls" that match label selector "", field selector "status.PostgresClusterStatus=Running": field label not supported: status.PostgresClusterStatus
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you also open https://github.com/zalando/postgres-operator/issues/1021? The error seems pretty clear. The resource operator doesn't support selecting on that field.

Comment: yes exactly. We have the same issue.